# Convert anchor point tool doesn't work the same as Illustrator? Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, pen-tool

I noticed the pen tool behaves a little differently in photoshop than it does in illustrator. I've created a curve and then an anchor point but then I want to have a straight path after that. I am trying to amend the second path because its curved. Using the convert anchor point tool I tried at first to click on the anchor because thats what you do in illustrator to make one side of the anchor point straight but it doesn't do anything.

I then tried to click the anchor point itself and it makes both lines straight.

[image]

[[image]][

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mis-remembering.

Use the **Convert Anchor Tool** and click the **Bezier handle** you wish to change. If you want to completely remove the handle from *one side* of an anchor on an existing path, then <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-click the **Bezier handle** you want to remove with the **Convert Anchor Tool**.

You don't actually want to click an anchor in the middle of a path with the Convert Anchor Tool unless you *want* to alter both sides of the anchor.

This is very similar to Illustrator pen operations (unless they've changed things in the last year, which is unlikely).